# Basic question on retain/release semantics from Apple's reference library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have done Objective-C way back when, and have recently (i.e. just now) read the documentation on Apple's site regarding the use of `retain` and `release`.  However, there is a bit of code in their [Creating an iPhone Application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007595) page that has me a bit confused:

```
- (void)setUpPlacardView
{
    // Create the placard view -- it calculates its own frame based on its image.
    PlacardView *aPlacardView = [[PlacardView alloc] init];
    self.placardView = aPlacardView;
    [aPlacardView release];  // What effect does this have on self.placardView?!
    placardView.center = self.center;
    [self addSubview:placardView];
}
```

Not seeing the entire class, it seems that `self.placardView` is also a `PlacardView *` and the assignment of it to `aPlacardView` doesn't seem to indicate it will retain a reference to it.  So, it appears to me that the line I've commented (`[aPlacardView release];`) could result in `aPlacardView` having a retain count of 0 and thus being deallocated.  Since `self.placardView` points to it, wouldn't that now point at deallocated memory and cause a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have done Objective-C way back when,

Hi, Obj-C introduced an (evil) concept of *properties* in the meantime. Note that

```
 self.placardView=xxx;
```

and

```
 self->placardView=xxx;
```

is different. The former, by definition, calls `[self setPlacardView:xxx]` whereas the latter just assigns `xxx` into a member.
Now, when you look at [MoveMeView.h](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/Listings/Classes_MoveMeView_h.html), you see the line

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) PlacardView *placardView;
```

and in [MoveMeView.m](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/Listings/Classes_MoveMeView_m.html)

```
@synthesize placardView;
```

These tell the compiler to generate  `-setPlacardView:` and `placardView` appropriately, using the standard retain/release semantics. For more details, see Apple's documentation for [properties](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html).

Comment: The concept of properties is not evil, it's the dot notation that Apple introduced at the same time.  It pollutes the syntax and causes endless confusion.  Personally, I use properties a lot, but I use normal Objective-C syntax to get and set them.

Comment: Yes I agree with that. That's why I put parentheses around the word evil to start with. For me the dot notation is perfectly OK; I always remind myself that these are method calls. But I heartily agree that it is a great source of confusion for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to point out;

*if* the property placardView is defined as being retained (@property (retain) ...) then self.placardView will call the setter generated by the compiler, which will include a retain.

Just incase this is new to you, properties and the associated @synthesize tell the compiler to generate `- (void)setPlacardView:(UIView *)view` and `- (UIView *)placardView` methods.

Another thing to note; addSubview: retains the view it's given. So without the release the view would have a retain count of 2. Releasing and then adding as a subview gives you a retain count of 1.